# Rmarkdown each chunk on separate pages

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown

My upper parameters of rmarkdown raport (.pdf) are:

````
---
title: "yyyyyyyyy"
author: "xxxxxxx"
output: pdf_document
classoption: landscape
---

I have some global options

```{r global_options, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, fig.width = 14, cache = T)
```
### chunk number 1

```{r}
some r code
```

### chunk number 2

```{r}
some r code
```

### chunk number 3

```{r}
some r code
```
````

I want to control output and have each chunk output on seperate pages in pdf report. How i can get it?

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves my problem.

Comment: I agree the answer is useful, but I think it isn't a duplicate. You could also make this happen by [editing the subsubsection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131015/page-break-after-every-section) to make a pagebreak before each title: https://gist.github.com/dr-harper/b0114c9fd762a5289c5b403b116da239